# Can not find Public API Access in google clould storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

From https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-javascript

```
/**
    * Enter the API key from the Google Developers Console, by following these
    * steps:
    * 1) Visit https://cloud.google.com/console and select your project
    * 2) Click on "APIs & auth" in the left column and then click “Credentials”
    * 3) Find section "Public API Access" and use the "API key." If sample is
    * being run on localhost then delete all "Referers" and save. Setting
    * should display "Any referer allowed." For more info see:
    * https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys
    */
```

I went to step 3, but I could not see Public API Access. Where can I find it?
here is my screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page has moved. Updated instructions:

1. Visit https://console.developers.google.com and select your project from the dropdown at the top.
2. Click on “Credentials” on the left menu bar.
3. Click the "Create credentials" drop down and select "API key".
4. Select "Browser Key"
5. If sample is being run on localhost then delete all "Referers" and save.

Comment: I am not able to see my project on the link you provided @jterrace, can you please help me out locating this?

Comment: The UI changed slightly again. I updated the answer.

Comment: Found it yesterday itself, but thanks for updating it could help others :)

Comment: "Browser key" seems to have disappeared